# Renaming the enterprise wiki page home page to an already exsisting name , will no longer define it as the home page

Tags: 2013, development, publishing-site, wiki, enterprise-wiki

I am working on an Enterprise wiki site collection , and i found this strange behavior:-

- Currently we have our home page URL as `/Welcome.aspx`
- Now if I edit the home page properties and i change the welcome page name to an existing name let say `WelcomeNew.aspx`, I will get the following error :-

> Sorry, something went wrong  The specified name is already in use.
>
> The document or folder name was not changed.  To change the name to a
>   different value, close this dialog and edit the properties of the
>   document or folder.

- Now if I refresh the error page I will get the following message:-

> Sorry, something went wrong  The file Pages/welcome.aspx has been
>   modified by i:0#.w|tdmgroup\administrator on 29 Apr 2015 16:22:54
>   +0100.  Technical Details
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.  Correlation
>   ID: 3e7f019d-b8d6-f084-3eee-fba720c56a3e  Date and Time: 29/04/2015
>   16:24:03

Then if I navigate to my site collection I will find that the welcome page became `WelocmeNew.aspx` instead of `Welcome.aspx` can anyone advice on this ?

Comment: Can you still see Welcome.aspx or tat got renamed?

Comment: now Welcome.aspx will still there, but the WelcomeNew.aspx will became the new home page,, now if i go to welcome.aspx and i set it as the home page everything will work fine,, but not sure why this is happening,, i mean if you rename ur home page to an existing name , the existing name wiki page will became the home page !!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found

1. You change home page to new name
2. SharePoint set site home page = new name
3. Tries to change the name of actual file

I believe step#2 should have been done after #3 or there should be a rollback mechanism

Comment: so it is a bug in sharepoint what do u think ?

Comment: Yes. I think so

Comment: but it is good that the welcome.aspx page content did not got replaced by the welcomeNew.aspx or vice versa !!!

Comment: Yes but it is worse if WelcomeNew.aspx doesn't exists.

Comment: i did not get your point what exactly you mean by " it is worse if WelcomeNew.aspx doesn't exists"

Comment: If you didn't had a page already existing with name = "WelcomeNew", then people will try to access site and get Page Not Found error.

Comment: now i think in that case users will be redirected to the new WelcomeNew.aspx page, as it will stay the home page because users will navigate to the site and not to a specific page they will navigate to url such as http://servername:1234/WikiSite and not to http://servername:1234/wikisite/pages/Welcome.aspx ..